# Checkbox y datepicker

Tags: html, jquery

Busco la forma que cuando se flagee el checkbox cambie el formato del datepicker.
Este es mi código de Jquery

```
$(document).on('click','#chk_out',function ()
{
    if ($('#chk_out').is(':checked'))
    {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "-15D", maxDate: "+0D" });
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
    }

    else
    {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "-1D", maxDate: "+0D" });
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
    }
});
```

Este el código de HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
            <h5>Incidencia extemporánea</h5><input type="checkbox" name="chk_out" id="chk_out" class="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Fecha del incidente</h5>
              <input type="text" id="fecha" class="datepicker" readonly>
            </div>
```

No lo está haciendo, me pueden apoyar? Gracias.
Hice este fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/neLp3naw/8/
Cuando se checkea el checkbox debería habilitarme 15 días atrás

Comment: ¿Podrías poner lo que introduces y lo que tendría que aparecer?

Comment: No introduzco nada, solo le doy click al checkbox me tendría que ampliar la selección de días a 15 días anteriores, pero se queda como nace, en 1 día.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en el que podamos ver su comportamiento?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/neLp3naw/8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisa este ejemplo, te lo explico:

Primero en `$(document).ready` inicializo desde un principio el `datepicker`, después allí mismo en `$(document).ready` agregue la función `$('#chk_out').change`, el truco para que funcione es que hay que destruir el `datepicker` cada vez que el `checkbox` cambie y volver a generar el control `datepicker` con las condiciones nuevas.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: "-1D",
    maxDate: "+0D",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });
  
 $('#chk_out').change(function() { 
   $(".datepicker").datepicker('destroy');
   if ($('#chk_out').is(':checked')) {
  console.log('menos 15 dias');
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     minDate: "-15D",
     maxDate: "+0D",
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
   } else {
  console.log('menos 1 dia');
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     minDate: "-1D",
     maxDate: "+0D",
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
   }
 });
  
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <h5>Incidencia extemporánea</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_out" id="chk_out" class="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <h5>Fecha del incidente</h5>
  <input type="text" id="fecha" class="datepicker" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Caracoles Cristina! Más Ladies Developers como tú. Muchas gracias, ya funcionó.

Comment: Me da mucho gusto haberte ayudado, saludos desde Sinaloa, Mexico :-)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo buena solucion!!!

Comment: @m3w  Gracias :-)